# Número al azar y poder usarlo

Tags: java

Buenas. Soy nuevo por aquí y más aun en programación en Java. Vereis, estoy intentando crear un programa ´básico´ para un trabajo y tengo algunas dudas.

Básicamente lo que quiero es generar un número al azar y poder asignárselo a un ´usuario´ de mi programa que tiene sus caracteristicas propias (nombre, edad...) y que más tarde, si yo introduzco ese código en mi programa, me dé la información de ese usuario.

Por ejemplo: Pepito tiene 32 años y tiene el código ´3´. Pues yo al poner ese código en otra parte del programa me diga que es ´Pepito el de 32 años.´

Espero haberme explicado bien y que podais resolverme esa dudilla. Un saludo.

Comment: Quizás suene un poco tonto, pero, ¿asumimos que el número aleatorio no se puede repetir? Para no relacionar el mismo código a dos o más usuarios.

Comment: Puedes compartir el código que ya tienes hecho? Sin eso, es difícil plantear una respuesta. Normalmente, no se suele responder a peticiones del tipo "hazme los deberes"

Comment: Caundo se reciben varias respuestas que disparan a todos los lados, eso es usualmente indicación de que la pregunta no es lo suficientemente específico.

Comment: No se porque tanto alboroto con esta pregunta ¿acaso no entienden lo que pide "Básicamente lo que quiero es generar un número al azar y poder asignárselo a un ´usuario´ de mi programa"? lo que yo entiendo es que le expliquen como generar un numero al azar y como lo quiere asignar a un usuario por ende este numero no debe coincidir con otro, sólo eso, acaso es tan complicado explicarle?

Comment: @AlbertoRojas si miras en las normas veras que los trabajos académicos deben llevar el código que se ha intentado, con un ejemplo claro. Este tipo de preguntas solo hace que la calidad del sitio caiga y cada vez se están repitiendo mas frecuentemente preguntas que deben ser cerradas y usuarios que no se preocupan por la normas que nos hemos dado como comunidad.

Answer (score 2):

Si no he entendido mal, lo que quieres es un identificador. Aunque puedes usar números al azar (mira la clase Random), te recomiendo que uses un contador para que todos los ids sean diferentes (que pasa si tanto Pepito como Pepe tienen el código 3?)

Para solucionar el problema que planteas se deben abordar 3 factores: estructurar datos de un usuario, generar ids aleatorios para asignarlos cuando se crea un usuario y guardar los datos de los usuarios de manera eficiente para poder acceder a ellos. Vayamos por partes:

1) **Estructurar los datos de los usuarios:** 
Usa una clase con los campos que has indicado  (nombre, edad y id).

```
// clase con los datos del usuario

class User {
    public String name;
    public Integer age;
    public Integer userId;

    // constructor
    public User(Integer userId, String name, Integer age){

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

2) **Generar ids aleatorios para asignarlos cuando se crea un usuario:**
Con las siguientes variables y funciones se generan ids aleatórios para poder asignar a los usuarios que se vayan creando. La función que genera números aleatorios NO es la más eficiente (cuando haya muchos usuarios y pocos ids libres puede tardar muchísimo), pero sí que es la función más simple y entendible que usa números aleatorios que se me ha ocurrido.

```
// variables y constantes para controlar qué ids ya se han usado
Set<Integer> usedIds = new HashSet<Integer>(); // conjunto de ids que ya se han usado
final int minId = 1;
final int maxId = 1000;

Integer generateNewRandomId(){
    // comprobamos que haya algun id libre (que no esté en usedIds)
    if(usedIds.size() >= (maxId - minId + 1)){
        return null;
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    int newId = -1;
    boolean correctId = false;

    // generamos números aleatorios hasta que salga uno que esté libre
    while(!correctId)
    {
        // asignamos a newId un nuevo número aleatorio entre minId y maxId (incluidos)
        newId = random.nextInt(maxId - minId + 1) + minId; 
        // newId sólo es válido si no se encuentra en usedIds
        correctId = !usedIds.contains(new Integer(newId));
    }
    return new Integer(newId);
}

// creadora del usuario
User createNewUser(String name, Integer age){
    Integer userId = generateNewRandomId();
    if(userId != null){
        return new User(userId,name, age);
    }
    return null;

}
```

3) **Guardar los datos de los usuarios de manera eficiente para poder acceder a ellos:**
Finalmente, para poder acceder a un usuario según el Id, tenemos que guardar sus datos. Como querremos acceder a los usuarios según su Id, usaremos un Map que nos relacione un Integer (el Id del usuario) con el propio usuario:

```
// variables para añadir al modelo usuarios y encontrar usuarios según Id
Map<Integer, User> users = new HashMap<Integer, User>();

void addUserToModel(User user){
    this.users.put(user.userId, user);
}

void createAndAddNewUser(String name, Integer age){
    User user = createNewUser(name,age);
    addUserToModel(user);
}

User getUserByUserId(Integer userId){
    return users.get(userId);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por los aportes MiquelColl y @Mariano, ya he expandido la respuesta :) Para las siguientes esperaré a que la pregunta sea más concisa (o si tengo suficiente reputación, ya pondré algún comentario :P)

Comment: Genial respuesta :)!!!!

Answer (score -2):

Bueno al ver que necesitas un identificador para cada usuario puedes usar el metodo **hashCode** que te proporciona la clase String donde dependiendo el nombre del usuario generara un identifcador siempre y cuando el nombre sea distinto.

```
        String p1 = "Jose matias rodriguez";
        String p2 = "Laura mendoza martinez";
        String p3 = "Rocio sanchez jimenez";

        System.out.println("Numero => "+p1.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Numero => "+p2.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Numero => "+p3.hashCode());
```

> Salida ejemplo:

```
  Numero => 922246917
  Numero => -490234343
  Numero => 1488370162
```

Comment: Hola Rene. Es mejor no sugerir esto, ya que `hashCode()` no ofrece ninguna garantía de que para dos cadenas distintas los hash codes siempre sean distintos. Claro, es poco probable, pero ¿para qué abusar una función que no está diseñado para eso?

Answer (score -2):

Supongo que guardas esos datos en un arreglo o en una lista, ya que si fuera base de datos no es necesario hacer eso. Lo que tienes que hacer es generar un numero aleatorio y luego verificar que no exista, podría ser de la siguiente forma...

```
       codigo = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 );
       while(tuListaDeNumerosgeneradosAnteriormente.constains(codigo)){
                 codigo = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 );
       }
       tuListaDeNumerosgeneradosAnteriormente.add(codigo);
```

Comment: ¿Y cuando tenga más de 100 usuarios, qué hace? ¿Vuelve a preguntar por qué el programa no le responde?

Answer (score -2):

Ok primero debes crear un objeto usuario e ir asignarle el código de forma aleatoria (Cosa nada recomendable para usar como identificador ya que los números podrían repetirse):

```
package mx.materiam.pruebitas;

import java.util.Random;

public class Usuario {

private String nombre;
private int edad;
private int codigo;

public Usuario() {
}

public Usuario(String nombre, int edad) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    codigo = new Random().nextInt();
    System.out.println("El codigo de "+nombre + " es : " + codigo);
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
}
```

Y pues lo siguiente es irlos agregando a una lista y crear una función para buscar por código y devolver el usuario y listo:

```
package mx.materiam.pruebitas;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class main {

public static  List<Usuario> usuarios = new LinkedList();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario("Pedro", 32);
    usuarios.add(usuario);
    Usuario usuario2 = new Usuario("Juan", 22);
    usuarios.add(usuario2);
    Usuario usuario3 = new Usuario("Ruby", 15);
    usuarios.add(usuario3);

    System.out.println(getUserByCode(usuario.getCodigo()).getNombre());
}

public static Usuario getUserByCode(int codigo) {
    Usuario user = new Usuario();

    for(Usuario u : usuarios)
        if(u.getCodigo()==codigo)
            user = u;

    return user;
}

}
```

Toma en cuenta que en este ejemplo los códigos SÍ podrían repetirse, pero como no mencionaste algo al respecto no lo tomé en cuenta y solo me limité a responder tu pregunta de acuerdo a la información que brindaste.

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene responder algo que no es recomendable?

Comment: Respondo preguntas, tal vez se lo pidieron para una tarea y le pidieron explícitamente que sea así. No lo sé, solo me limito a responder aclarando el por qué no es recomendable.

Answer (score -3):

Hola te voy a dejar un ejemplo donde obtengas un numero al azar, aun que de esta forma podrías asignarle el mismo numero a un usuario, tendrías que validar si ya existe ese numero que genere otro o utilizar un contador, o que el campo idUsuario por ejemplo sea un auto-incrementable(Serial).

```
package mx.com.softmolina;

/**
 *
 * @author softmolina
 */
public class EjemploNumeroAleatorio {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        //genera un numero entre el 1 al 100(el 100 se puede cambiar hasta el numero que quieres que llegue) 
        //y lo guarda en la variable numeroAleatorio,(el +1 es para que nunca tengas un cero)
        int numeroAleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;

        //imprime el numero en consola
        System.out.println(numeroAleatorio);

    }

}
```

Comment: Si votan en contra deberían decir por que o sera que no tienen argumentos¿?

Comment: Mi voto negativo te lo doy porque lo único que haces es generar un número aleatorio, pero luego dejas pendiente otro problema identificado. Por otra parte, este tipo de preguntas es mejor no responderlas tal cual está hecha. Si miras el centro de ayuda queda claro el por qué. Un usuario con tu reputación debería conocer ya algunas cosas de este sitio.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Tal ves tienes razón, y se le esta respondiendo lo que necesita y se le esta indicando que problema podría tener y opciones para solucionarlo, no le das una respuesta concreta al problema identificado por que no se sabe que hay detrás pero se le esta dando seguimiento.